# Kiel oni diras «mac and cheese»?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ankaŭ konata kiel «macaroni and cheese». Oni nomu tiun mirindan pastaĵon. Vortojn, vortojn, vortojn mi enmetas por laŭigi ĉi tiun afiŝon.

Answer (score 5):

Mi pensas ke tre facilas traduki la nomon de tiu manĝaĵo: "makaronioj kun fromaĝo"

Answer (score 5):

Memoru ke naciaj manĝaĵoj ne havas nomojn en internacia lingvo. Oni ne supozu ke homoj el aliaj landoj konos tiun manĝon. Malgraŭ tiu averto, en nia domo ni diras **makaronioj kaj fromaĝo** aŭ eventuale **kubutoj kaj fromaĝo.**

Se vi sentas vin iom klarigema vi povus diri **makaronia kaserolaĵo en fromaĝsaŭco**.

Comment: Eble kun fromaĝo pli taŭgus, aŭ kiel vi diris en la pli detala respondo, en fromaĝo.

Comment: Eble, sed mi ne vidas grandan diferencon ĉe "kun" kaj ĉe "kaj". Cetere, mi sentas diferencon inter "mi trinkas kafon kun kremo" kaj "mi trinkas kafon kaj kremon." La dua estas pli krema. Mac-and-cheese ja estas fromaĝa! Tial mi diras "kaj fromaĝo" aŭ "**en** fromaĝsaŭco."